# Terminate key binding not working in eclipse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I'm moving over to eclipse from visual studio 2005 and am used to these key bindings:

- *F7* = build
- *F5* = build & run (debug)
- *Shift-F5* = stop running
- *Ctrl-Shift-F5* = stop running & build & run again

With eclipse there is:

- *Ctrl-B* = build
- *Ctrl F11* = run
- *Shift-F11* = stop running (terminate)
- *Ctrl-Shift-F11* = terminate and relaunch (presumably building anything it needs to as well)

I set the last two in *Window->Preferences->General->Key* and they do not work. I have to click the red square on the console view to terminate the application or else if I do *Ctrl-F11* again it will fail since the exe is still running in the background.

I tried setting the *When* field in the key bindings to:

- In Console View
- In C/C++ Views
- In Windows
- C/C++ Editor
- Debugging c++

None of these work and there doesn't appear to be a "when anything is running" option. Run is set to "In Windows" and works both when running and debugging so it would make sense that Terminate would as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Use *F11* to debug instead of *Ctrl-F11* to run and then both of the terminate shortcuts work.